# How may I ignore some folders/files from webpack compiling

Tags: webpack

I'm using webpack 3.8.1 for compiling my VueJS project, there are quite many js files, and take time for re-compiling everytime I save a js file.

Now I want to ignore folders which not changed frequently, then webpack doesn't need to compile all files (of course, at the first time, all those file must be included for compiling), but I don't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
{ exclude: Condition }
```

specify the file name in Condition.  Remove the condition for first time compilation.

Comment: Thanks @Akhilesh for your answer, but we will need to change configuration everytime after start app, are there any way for add a flag or new job or something else

Comment: No, there is not @KhoiNguyen